# replace all occurences of colon and values around it for a tab

Tags: sed, replace

Thanks for the help.
I have done this:

```
cat file1.txt | sed 's/1:2=//'| sed 's/1:3=//'| sed 's/1:4=//'| sed 's/1:5=//'| sed 's/1:6=//'| sed 's/2:3=//'| sed 's/2:4=//'| sed 's/2:5=//'| sed 's/2:6=//'| sed 's/3:4=//'| sed 's/3:5=//'| sed 's/3:6=//'| sed 's/4:5=//'| sed 's/4:6=//'| sed 's/5:6=//' > file2.txt
```

and I am happy, but now I have a file with many more combinations (all possible among 16 treatments, not just 3 as in the example above) and I don't want to type all 120 combinations. can you help me find a way to replace all occurrences of the colons and the numbers around them for a space?

Comment: A single digit is matched by `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`

Comment: We need sample input and expected output. Also, we don't know if it is just a coincidence that the last number n2 always goes from n1+1 to 6 because you don't explicitly mention it, or if we could simply use `[[:digit:]]`, as suggested, to tackle all in one go.

Answer (score 1):

The art here is to find a regular expression that matches your requirements.

For example,

```
sed 's/[0-9]:[0-9]=//'
```

will match all the patterns that you have written-out, but it will also match `3:2=`, which might not be what you want.

But you should be able to use, for example:

```
sed 's/1:[2-6]=//;s/2:[3-6]=//;s/3:[4-6]=//;s/4:[56]=//;s/5:6=//'
```

which is already much less typing.

If your numbers are larger than a single digit, this becomes a problem. You can spit in two the patterns, for example:

```
s/5:[6-9]=//;s/5:1[0-6]=//
```

but at some point, `awk` or `perl`  seem more appropriate tools.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
  
while (<>){
    chomp;
    if (/(.*)([0-9]+):([0-9]+)=(.*)/){
        if ($2<$3){
            print "$1$4";
        }
        else {
            print "$1$2i:$3=$4\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: now I got :   sed: -e expression #1, char 14: Invalid range end

Comment: I ran:cat file.txt | sed 's/1:[2-16]=//;s/2:[3-16]=//;s/3:[4-16]=//;s/4:[5-16]=//;s/5:[6-16]=//;s/6:[7-16]=//;s/7:[8-16]=//;s/8:[9-16]=//;s/9:[10-16]=//;s/10:[11-16]=//;s/11:[12-16]=//;s/12:[13-16]=//;s/13:[14-16]=//;s/14:[15:16]=//;s/15:16=//'| > file2.txt

Comment: @MaripazCelorio please show us an example of your input file and the output you want from it as you were [asked to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618743/replace-all-occurences-of-colon-and-values-around-it-for-a-tab#comment1157380_618743) an hour ago. We can't help you parse data if you don't show us the data we need to parse, so without an example anything we give you will be a guess.

Comment: 2:[3-16]= means: '2' ':'  all characters >3 and <1, or 6. The range >3, but <1 is an invalid range. I think you want something more powerfull than sed here...

Answer (score 0):

this worked!

```
sed 's/[0-9]*:[0-9]*=//g' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To remove all occurrences of `<integer1>:<integer2>=` where `<integer1>` is less than `<integer2>`, you could do:

```
<file perl -pe 's{(\d+):(\d+)=}{$1 < $2 ? "" : $&}ge'
```

On `1:2= 20:3= 5:5=`, that would give  `20:3= 5:5=`.